# Convert String array to Map using Java 8 Lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Is there a better functional way of converting an array of Strings in the form of "key:value" to a `Map` using the Java 8 lambda syntax?

```
Arrays.asList("a:1.0", "b:2.0", "c:3.0")
        .stream()
        .map(elem -> elem.split(":")
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper?, valueMapper?));
```

The solution I have right now does not seem really functional:

```
Map<String, Double> kvs = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.asList("a:1.0", "b:2.0", "c:3.0")
        .stream()
        .map(elem -> elem.split(":"))
        .forEach(elem -> kvs.put(elem[0], Double.parseDouble(elem[1])));
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can modify your solution to collect the `Stream` of `String` arrays into a `Map` (instead of using `forEach`) :

```
Map<String, Double> kvs =
    Arrays.asList("a:1.0", "b:2.0", "c:3.0")
        .stream()
        .map(elem -> elem.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> Double.parseDouble(e[1])));
```

Of course this solution has no protection against invalid input. Perhaps you should add a filter just in case the split String has no separator :

```
Map<String, Double> kvs =
    Arrays.asList("a:1.0", "b:2.0", "c:3.0")
        .stream()
        .map(elem -> elem.split(":"))
        .filter(elem -> elem.length==2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> Double.parseDouble(e[1])));
```

This still doesn't protect you against all invalid inputs (for example `"c:3r"` would cause `NumberFormatException` to be thrown by `parseDouble`).

Comment: I don't think that silently ignoring erroneous input is a good advice and this was not requested by OP. I'd better use `elem -> elem.split(":", 2)` instead of adding the `filter` step. This way erroneous input will be manifested either by `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (if no colon was found) or by `NumberFormatException` (if more than one colon was found).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and additional input on the error checking. This is what I needed.

Comment: If task is to convert a *real* array to Map, then the expression should start with `Arrays.stream(<arrayVariable>)`

Comment: @Vlad.Bachurin It also works with the current code - `Arrays.asList(<arrayVariable>).stream()...`. The `Arrays.asList("a:1.0", "b:2.0", "c:3.0")` part was taken as is from the question.

Comment: @Eran `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List`. Someone may have a real array.

Comment: @Vlad.Bachurin It returns a List, but it accepts an array.

Comment: @Eran I got your point, but `Arrays.stream(<array>)` is shorter anyway. And fits better the subject of the question. Peace. :)

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Jamie that was careless of me. Thanks again!