# convert list into map

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have below list, i want to convert list to map.

```
SurveyAllocationUsers user1 = new SurveyAllocationUsers();
    user1.setSurveyorId("1");
    user1.setSurveyorTypeCode("LSR");

    SurveyAllocationUsers user2 = new SurveyAllocationUsers();
    user2.setSurveyorId("1");
    user2.setSurveyorTypeCode("SR");

    SurveyAllocationUsers user3 = new SurveyAllocationUsers();
    user3.setSurveyorId("2");
    user3.setSurveyorTypeCode("LSR");

    SurveyAllocationUsers user4 = new SurveyAllocationUsers();
    user4.setSurveyorId("2");
    user4.setSurveyorTypeCode("SR");

    SurveyAllocationUsers user5 = new SurveyAllocationUsers();
    user5.setSurveyorId("2");
    user5.setSurveyorTypeCode("BG");

    List<SurveyAllocationUsers> list = new ArrayList<SurveyAllocationUsers>();

    list.add(user1);list.add(user2);list.add(user3);list.add(user4);list.add(user5);
```

want to convert list to map like below.

```
Map<String,List<String>> usersMap = new  HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

map key will be SurveyorId and values will be correspondiing List of SurveyorTypeCode.

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: Try writing the code rather than giving us hints

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693781/convert-string-array-to-map-using-java-8-lambda-expressions] if using java 8 .

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like below

```
userMap.put(user1.getSurveyorId(), new ArrayList<>().add(user1.getSurveyorTypeCode));

userMap.put(user2.getSurveyorId(), new ArrayList<>().add(user2.getSurveyorTypeCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
List<SurveyAllocationUsers> list = new ArrayList<SurveyAllocationUsers>();

list.add(user1);list.add(user2);list.add(user3);list.add(user4);list.add(user5);
Map<String,List<String>> usersMap = new  HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for(SurveyAllocationUsers sau: list){
   if(!userMap.contains(sau.getSurveyorId())){
    userMap.put(sau.getSurveyorId(), new ArrayList<>().add(sau.getSurveyorTypeCode));
   }else{
    userMap.get(sau.getSurveyorId()).add(sau.getSurveyorTypeCode);
   }
}
```

Note: Code in not complied.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit ugly but solves your problem:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(toMap(SurveyAllocationUsers::getSurveyorId, p -> new ArrayList(singletonList(p.getSurveyorTypeCode())), (s, a) -> {               
            s.addAll(a);
            return s;
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> usersMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (SurveyAllocationUsers user : list) {
    List<String> typeCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    typeCodes.add(user.getSurveyorTypeCode());
    usersMap.put(user.getSurveyorId(), typeCodes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your reply, I got the solution as below.

```
List <String>newUserList = null;
    Map<String,List<String>> usersMap = new  HashMap<String, List<String>>();       
    for(SurveyAllocationUsers sau: list){
        if(usersMap.containsKey(sau.getSurveyorId())){

            List <String>myList = usersMap.get(sau.getSurveyorId());
            myList.add(sau.getSurveyorTypeCode());
            usersMap.put(sau.getSurveyorId(), myList);

        }else{
            if(sau.getSurveyorId() != null){
                newUserList = new ArrayList<String>();
                newUserList.add(sau.getSurveyorTypeCode());
                usersMap.put(sau.getSurveyorId(), newUserList);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer as expected
1     [LSR, SR]
2     [LSR, SR, BG]

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this using Java8

```
resMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SurveyAllocationUsers::getSurveyorId,
                Collectors.mapping(SurveyAllocationUsers::getSurveyorTypeCode,Collectors.toList())));
```

> Output: {1=[LSR, SR], 2=[LSR, SR, BG]}